# convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD and now() in impala

Tags: sql, date, casting, impala

i have a query like this

```
select
sources,
table_name,
position
from prd_sri_datalake.sri_300_300_monitoring_daily_new
where cast(date_process as DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
= cast(now() as DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```

for date_process has the format YYYYMMDD which i want to display as YYYY-MM-DD.
i want to display data where date_process is equal to the current time, but i try to cast in impala it can't.
can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you want to check if date_process = current_date or not ?

You can convert date_process to timestamp without time like this
`to_timestamp(date_process,'yyyyMMdd')` and then equate with current date without time like this `trunc(now(),'DD')`.
Where clause would look like this

```
where to_timestamp(date_process,'yyyyMMdd')= trunc(now(),'DD') --date to date match
```

You can also do like you did - convert everything to yyyyMMdd and equate.

```
where date_process= from_timestamp(now(),'yyyyMMdd') --string to string match
```

EDIT : convert date_process from 'YYYYMMDD' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' can be done like this - convert this to timestamp first using to_timestamp and then convert to string using from_timestamp.

```
from_timestamp(to_timestamp(date_process,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') as date_process_str_yyyy_MM_dd
```

Comment: position and date_process are of type string data, with data format 'YYYYMMDD', I want to change it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' and match the latest date where the date format is also 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: i added `EDIT` to the answer. could you pls chk?

Comment: iI've tried the query but it returns a null value

Comment: can you pls post your updated SQL? what is this latest date data type? it will be much cleared if post your 1. input data and data type and the logic 2. expected data and type.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong with this answer?